# HTML5 how to bind local database to asp gridview

Tags: jquery, html, gridview

I have a site with HTML5 and a local database, i want to bind a table from the local database to the asp gridview using jquery code, how do i do that>

Does anyone have an example for that?

Thanks,

Comment: try telerik components: http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using DataTables.net for that.

I use it for some of my projects and it works great, there are tons of plugins for it too.

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

That example will show you how to bind the datatables to an ajax request.

Just create a JSONResult action that will return the structure needed and it will bind.

Hope that helps, best of luck.

Comment: I believe the OP is talking about local databases supported within the browser itself, and not binding to an AJAX endpoint.